# NetBSD build failing due to .DS_Store file Macintosh

Tags: macos, kernel, netbsd

I am trying to build the NetBSD kernel using

```
$ ./build.sh -O ../obj.amd64 -U -u -m amd64 -j4 tools release iso-image
```

It fails with the output

```
=======  1 extra files in DESTDIR  =========
Files in DESTDIR but missing from flist.
File is obsolete or flist is out of date ?
------------------------------------------
./.DS_Store
=========  end of 1 extra files  ===========
*** [checkflist] Error code 1

nbmake[2]: stopped in /Volumes/NetBSDImage/src/distrib/sets
1 error
```

Even when I do an 
`rm .DS_Store` in /Volumes/NetBSDImage/src/distrib/sets, it fails with the same message.
Earlier, when I compiled the kernel without the `iso-image` option, it build successfully, but now, even that fails. Some help?

Comment: How about disable the generation of DS_Store, delete current one and try again?

Comment: @李骏骁 Is this the right way? $ defaults write com.apple.desktopservices DSDontWriteNetworkStores true

Comment: @李骏骁 Nope, this doesn't work.

Comment: I think it's the right way to disable. You mean it still generates the DS_Store or your build still not work? I think you need to restart the computer for this command to take effect.

Comment: @李骏骁 Yes, I did that and rebooted it too. It's not generating the .DS_Store file, but the build still fails saying that it still exists. This build is on a disk image, actually, so could that be a source of the problem?

Comment: Look back to your error log, it mentioned DESTDIR, maybe you can try to assign a DESTDIR folder by adding '-D destfolder'.

Answer (score 0):

The best I could come up with is a work around and not a solution.

The DS_Store files are generated only when you open them in the Finder app of Mac systems. 
So, on deleting and recloning the entire repository, it built successfully.

Answer (score 0):

I can crosscompile NetBSD-current fine from OS X without those files getting in the way. Did you do some manual work in destdir? Try removing the bad files then retry.